# Symfony2 : export csv error

Tags: php, symfony, csv, export-to-csv

I am doing data exporting by **CSV** format.

Problem : When data contains white space then it jumps column in csv file

[image]

In Image check at customer_id = 8

in address1 correct value is "starline appartment" But "starline" stay in address1 and "appartment" goes in address2.

This is controller code

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('db1');
        $connection = $em->getConnection();

        $query = "SELECT * 
                  FROM customers
                  ORDER BY customer_id ASC
                  LIMIT 10";
        $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $rows = $statement->fetchAll();
        $columns = $em->getClassMetadata('AdminSporteventsBundle:Customers')->getFieldNames();
        foreach ($columns as $value) {
            $finalcolumns[] = strtolower(preg_replace('/\B([A-Z])/', '_$1', $value));
        }        
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($rows);echo "</pre>";die;
        $response = $this->render('AdminSporteventsBundle:Export:export.csv.twig', array('data' => $rows));
        $filename = "export_".date("Y_m_d_His").".csv";
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename='.$filename);
        return $response;
```

And this is my view file code

```
cusromer_id, email_id, facebook_id, password, forname, surname, house_no, address1, address2, town, country, postcode, mobile, telepnone, created_date, updated_date
{% for customer in data %}
{{ customer.customer_id }}, {{ customer.email_id }}, {{ customer.facebook_id }}, {{ customer.password }}, {{ customer.forname }}, {{ customer.surname }}, {{ customer.house_no }}, {{ customer.address1 }}, {{ customer.address2 }}, {{ customer.town }}, {{ customer.country }}, {{ customer.postcode }}, {{ customer.mobile }}, {{ customer.telepnone }}, {{ customer.created_date }}, {{ customer.updated_date }}
{% endfor %}
```

So what can I do to solved this ?

Comment: us `" "` double quotes around each string value in your template.  But if the program that you are using to view the CSV is splitting a value based on a space, then it almost seems like that program is using a space as the delimiter, not a comma.  Double check that as well.

Comment: I had difficulties using twig to generate csv.  I went with a fputcsv approach.  Let us know if you get the twig working.  If not, I'll post a different way to go about this.

Comment: @Cerad : My Code is working. Problem is in that tool that is  I am using to see data. It uses space instead of comma. Problem Solved. Thanks for answering.